# Add a static border to a view that has a dynamic background

Tags: android, android-layout

I've searched SO for a while but couldn't find an answer to my exact question. I usually found 2 *similar* problems that do not suit my needs:

- Many people asked for how to draw a border around a view, and the solution is often to use a shape with a `stroke` as the background of the view. But this uses a static background.
  I can't use this (or don't know how in my case), because I'm creating a color picker and I draw the background programmatically.
- Other people asked how to draw a border programmatically, but that's only a fallback option for me.

One solution obviously came to my mind: wrapping my view with dynamic background in another view with the stroke. But I don't like this one as it unnecessarily complicates the layout, and could have an impact on performance too. I'd rather draw the border programmatically with the background than use nested views.

Hence my question:

**Is there a clean (androidic) way to set the border of a view in the XML when the background is set programmatically (without using nested views)?**

If not, I guess I'll just go for a dynamic stroke.

Comment: use setBackground[Drawable] with GradientDrawable object as a parameter

Comment: @pskink the question is about adding a border in XML when doing this for the background, I already have a gradient background. I reformulated the question to be clearer.

Comment: sorry  then,  i dont know what you want to do,  do you want to change the color of your shape?

Comment: @pskink I set the gradient background of a view programmatically, and I would like to add a border to it with XML.

Comment: ok,  so whats the problem?  Resources.getDrawable gives you an xml Drawable so you can call setBackground(Drawable) or you can call it directly by setBacgroundResource(int)

Comment: @pskink Calling `setBackgroundResource(int)` or any other method is what I call doing it *programmatically* (even if you get something from XML). What I wanted to do is to specify the border in the XML description of my view, without adding anything to the java code.

Comment: seems that i still dont understand since obviously android:background="@drawable/xxx" is not what you need?

Comment: @pskink If I do that, then this will be overwritten when I set the background dynamically in code with the gradient (at least, that's what I think, do you confirm?). I need 2 things: the border and the gradient. I set the latter with Java code, I'd like to set the former in the XML. The problem is, both are contained in the same property: the background.

Comment: you can use one GradientDrawable for both,  see ithe docs

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own view which does the same as your current view but with an added border.
I haven't tried this yet so I apologize for the lack of information but I believe this should be possible.